# activity stacking over existing activity

Tags: java, android

I got a little problem with my android app. It is an app to determine the steadiness of hand using accelerometer.I have two activities, Vert.java and Calcu.java. In Vert.java there is an animation function comprising of 25 png files. It also has the functions to retrieve the acceleromter values of x,y and z axes. A combined value is transferred to Calcu.java, where scores are given for specific range of values using if loop.But, while running the "Calcu" activity is reappearing. I am new to android. Please help.

These are my codes..

**Vert.java**

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Vert extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
    Sensor accelerometer1;
    SensorManager sm1;
    float x1=0,y1=0,z1=0,tx1=0,ty1=0,tz1=0,oldx1=0,oldy1=0,oldz1=0,totalx1=0,totaly1=0,totalz1=0;
    Intent m1;  
    int z;
    ImageView img;
    Timer timer;
    Handler handler;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in,R.anim.slide_out);
        setContentView(R.layout.vert);
        sm1=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer1=sm1.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sm1.registerListener(this, accelerometer1,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivAnim);
        AnimationDrawable animation=new AnimationDrawable();
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.b),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.c),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.e),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.g),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.h),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.i),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.j),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.k),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.l),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.m),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.n),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.o),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.p),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.q),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.r),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.s),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.t),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.u),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.v),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.w),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.x),200);
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.y),200);
    animation.setOneShot(false);
    img.setImageDrawable(animation);
    animation.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        x1=event.values[0];
        y1=event.values[1];
        z1=event.values[2];

        timer=new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                oldx1=x1;
                oldy1=y1;
                oldz1=z1;

                            }

        }, 200, 200);

        String str=String.valueOf(tx1);
        m1=new Intent(Vert.this,Calcu.class);
        m1.putExtra("score", str);


        if(oldx1>x1){
            totalx1=oldx1-x1;
        }
        else if(x1>oldx1){
            totalx1=x1-oldx1;
        }
        if(oldy1>y1){
            totaly1=oldy1-y1;
        }
        else if(y1>oldy1){
            totaly1=y1-oldy1;
        }
        if(oldz1>z1){
            totalz1=oldz1-z1;
        }
        else if(z1>oldz1){
            totalz1=z1-oldz1;
        }
        tx1=tx1+(totalx1+totaly1+totalz1);
         handler=new Handler();
         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(Vert.this.m1);
                m1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                finish();
        }

         },5000);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        this.sm1.unregisterListener(this);
        timer.cancel();


    }

}
```

**Vert.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/vertpageplain"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvVertHead"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="30dp"
         android:textColor="#138808"
        android:text="KEEP YOUR HANDS STEADY TILL THE BOTTLE GETS EMPTY..." />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivAnim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Calcu.java**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Calcu extends Activity{
    float krip1;
    double score1;
    String sScore;
    TextView finalScore1;
    ImageButton bB1,bS1,bE1;
    Bitmap b;
    Intent intent,chooser;
    Uri imageUri;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in,R.anim.slide_out);
        setContentView(R.layout.result);
        String pky1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("score");
        krip1=Float.valueOf(pky1);
        finalScore1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvScore1);
        bB1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bMain1);
        bS1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bShare1);
        bE1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bExit1);
        bB1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent n=new Intent(Calcu.this,Play.class);
                n.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                n.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(n);

            }
        });
        bS1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(score1==10){
                       b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scorea);

                   }
                   else if(score1==9.5){
                      b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scoreb);
                   }
                   else if(score1==9){
                          b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scorec);
                       }
                   else if(score1==8.5){
                          b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scored);
                       }
                   else if(score1==8){
                          b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scoree);
                       }
                   else if(score1==7.5){
                          b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scoref);
                       }
                   else if(score1==7){
                          b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scoreg);
                       }
                   else if(score1==6.5){
                              b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scoreg);
                           }
                   else if(score1==6){
                              b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scorei);
                           }
                   else if(score1==5.5){
                              b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scorej);
                           }
                   else if(score1==5){
                              b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scorek);
                           }
                   else if(score1==4.5){
                              b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scorel);
                           }
                   else if(score1==4){
                                  b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scorem);
                               }
                   else if(score1==3.5){
                                  b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scoren);
                               }
                  else if(score1==3){
                                  b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scoreo);
                               }
                  else if(score1==2.5){
                                  b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scorep);
                               }
                  else if(score1==2){
                                  b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scoreq);
                               }
                  else if(score1==1.5){
                                      b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scorer);
                                   }
                  else if(score1==1){
                                      b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scores);
                                   }
                  else if(score1==0.5){
                                      b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scoret);
                                   }
                  else if(score1==0){
                      b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.scoreu);
                   }    
                intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                   intent.setType("image/png");
                   ByteArrayOutputStream bytes=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                   b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
                   String path=MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "Title", null);
                   imageUri=Uri.parse(path);
                   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "SOBER SCORE CHALLENGE");
                   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sober score : "+score1+"What's your's?");
                   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
                   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is beta version. The final version will soon be available in play store.");
                   chooser=Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share your Sober Score...");
                   startActivity(chooser);
            }
        });
        bE1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent exit=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                exit.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                exit.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                startActivity(exit);
            }
        });
        if(krip1<90){
            score1=10;

        }
        else if(90<krip1 && krip1<100){
            score1=9.5;

        }
        else if(100<krip1 && krip1<110){
            score1=9;

        }
        else if(110<krip1 && krip1<135){
            score1=8.5;

        }
        else if(135<krip1 && krip1<150){
            score1=8;

        }
        else if(150<krip1 && krip1<160){
            score1=7.5;

        }
        else if(160<krip1 && krip1<175){
            score1=7;

        }
        else if(175<krip1 && krip1<185){
            score1=6.5;

        }
        else if(185<krip1 && krip1<195){
            score1=6;

        }
        else if(195<krip1 && krip1<210){
            score1=5.5;

        }
        else if(210<krip1 && krip1<215){
            score1=5;

        }
        else if(215<krip1 && krip1<225){
            score1=4.5;

        }
        else if(225<krip1 && krip1<245){
            score1=4;

        }
        else if(245<krip1 && krip1<265){
            score1=3.5;

        }
        else if(265<krip1 && krip1<285){
            score1=3;

        }
        else if(285<krip1 && krip1<305){
            score1=2.5;

        }
        else if(305<krip1 && krip1<335){
            score1=2;

        }
        else if(335<krip1 && krip1<365){
            score1=1.5;

        }
        else if(365<krip1 && krip1<395){
            score1=1;

        }
        else if(395<krip1 && krip1<425){
            score1=0.5;

        }

        else if(krip1>425){
            score1=0;


        }

        finalScore1.setText(""+score1+"");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent back=new Intent(Calcu.this,MainActivity.class);
        back.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        back.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(back);
        Calcu.this.finish();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        finish();
    }


}
```

**Result.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/resultpageplain"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/sobercent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvScore1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="70dp"
         android:textColor="#138808"
        android:text="X" />
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bMain1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bplayagain" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bShare1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="0dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bshare" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/bExit1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/bexit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have no idea who upvoted this, but it's impossible to understand the question if any.

Comment: removing this line might help m1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
use this m1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Comment: Add android:launchMode="singleTask" in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the below code snip it should work

```
      @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(Vert.this.m1);
            m1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            finish();
    }
```

Comment: Thats great Cheers!